# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

So I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in Java. I know there are different ways to do it but here's the way that I've learned to do it. So I start with a single vertex and I find the shortest path from that vertex to every other vertex. I start with a single vertex (in my case it's zero) and then update my neighborhood by relaxing all the edges connected to that vertex. I then find out what's the smallest edge that connects to the current edge and then I add that vertex to my vertex storage. I keep doing that until all the vertices are in my vertex storage and then I should end up with a type of spanning tree that shows me all the shortest paths.

So in my code, I'm trying to find the shortest path from 0 to 1. I get the graphs from an adjacency matrix. So what I do is I start at the first row (or the 0th row) and traverse through the row and relax the vertices in a matrix called N. I then find the smallest edge coming out of whatever vertices I have stored in my vertex storage and then contnue adding vertices and relaxing the edges. So then I have two main arrays called N (where I store the weights of the shortest paths) and edgeStorage. Here's what it looks like:

```
static int ShortestPath(int[][] G){
    int numVerts = G.length;
    int totalWeight = 0;

    int minWeight;
    int count = 1;
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int next = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int[] N = new int[numVerts];
    int[] edgeStorage = new int[numVerts];
    Arrays.fill(N, 2147483647); //2147483647 is my infinity to represent vertices that haven't yet been relaxed
    N[0] = 0;

    while (count != numVerts){
        for (int j = 0; j < numVerts; j++){
            if ((G[i][j] != 0) && (N[i] + G[i][j] < N[j])){
                N[j] = N[i] + G[i][j];
            }
        }
        minWeight = 2147483647;
        for (int p = 0; p < count; p++){ //find min edge weight for vertices in storage
            i = edgeStorage[p];
            for (int j = 0; j < numVerts; j++){
                if ((G[i][j] != 0) && (G[i][j] < minWeight)){
                    minWeight = G[i][j];
                    k = j;
                    l = i;
                }
            }
        }
        G[l][k] = 0; //remove edge since we don't need it anymore
        G[k][l] = 0;
        edgeStorage[next] = k; //store vertex location in array
        i = k;
        count++;
        next++;
    }
    totalWeight = N[1];
    return totalWeight;
}
```

The problem is this code works for some graphs but for others it gives me a weight that's bigger than it's supposed to be. I tested it on a graph of 25 vertices which looked like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 418 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 472 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 537 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 191 375 161 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 108 0 0 0 512 0 311 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 612 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 583 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 365 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 262 243 0 0 0 0 617 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 581 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
418 0 0 0 365 0 0 0 0 0 0 338 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 320 0 517 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 524 0 314 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 612 0 0 0 320 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 577 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 145 414 0 0 35 0 0 0 0 0 0 394 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 517 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 353 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 338 0 0 145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 344 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 108 0 0 0 0 0 0 414 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 607 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 581 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 609 0 0 231 0 0
472 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 478 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 262 0 0 0 0 35 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 280 0 0 0 0
0 0 512 0 243 0 0 0 577 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 353 0 607 0 478 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 594 0
0 0 311 0 0 0 0 524 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 471 0 0 306
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 344 0 609 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 583 0 0 0 314 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 280 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 214
0 191 0 0 617 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 471 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 375 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 394 0 0 0 231 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
537 161 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 594 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 306 0 214 0 0 0 0
```

My N array looked like this:

`0 1670 1538 1799 783 2107 418 1530 1603 901 2047 756 1315 1526 472 936 1026 950 1736 1100 1216 1400 1295 537 1430`

and my edgeStorage array looked like this:

```
0 6 11 9 15 4 16 20 24 18 2 12 7 8 19 4 22 13 1 23 21 12 21 14 17
```

So therefore it returned 1670 as the path between 0 and 1 when it should've returned 698. I have no idea why it gives me the wrong weight for some graphs but the right weight for others. So does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

P.S: I know my implementation is not the most efficient thing right now but I just want to get the basic implementation working and then I'll work on making it more efficient.